# Why didn't header files catch on in other programming languages?

Tags: c#, java, c++

Based on the response to this question: [Why does C++ have header files and CPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/in-c-why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files)

I have seen the responses and understand the answers - so why didn't this catch on?  C# Java?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because it's a quick, dirty and inelegant solution to the problem of interface vs. implementation.

It relies entirely on the C Preprocessor, which is about the bluntest tool in the drawer.

Other solutions avoid the following problems:

- Two files where one will do
- Duplicate symbols at link-time due to multiple definitions
- Code bloat due to multiple 'static' constants
- requirement for header guards to prevent multiple inclusion
- violation of DRY principles
- and more...

[Dviljoen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29021/dviljoen) thinks I'm being quite hard on it, and he's right. It is almost a [40-year old design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#Early_developments), from the era of punch cards and paper tape. There's an incredible amount of high-quality software built in C/C++ using the source/header file arrangement, despite all the potential gotchas and problems listed above.

Comment: But it also allows for some niceties, like deciding what should be in the public interface (the functions in the header file) and hidden stuff (e.g. static functions in the .c file).

Comment: @csl : there are many better ways of achieving that. Delphi has separate "implementation" and "interface" sections within a single file, for example.

Comment: While I do like the separation header/source in C/C++, and dislike the "one source" vision in Java, I agree with everything you said. +1

Comment: @csl: What's wrong with public / private?

Comment: You are correct, but man!  Give 'em a break.  Its 30+ years old.  Yes, we've moved on.  At the time the preprocessor was the ONLY tool in the drawer.  And you know what they say: when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: There's no header/source separation in C/C++. The header still contains source code (and particularly, class definitions contain much more than "a public interface". They contain instance variables and private functions too, which should not be visible). Headers are just an awful idea today.

Comment: Duplicate symbols exist in any language that has multiple translation units, unless each such unit also is a namespace. You simply can't have two different classes A::B::X.

Comment: @MSalters - with header files, there's a common anti-pattern where learners accidentally put DEFINITIONS instead of DECLARATIONS in headers - causing duplicate definition errors.

Answer (score 8):

Because it means to duplicate information which you can get from the source code. Other languages try to avoid this code duplication.

In my old C days, I did the same. I kept all information in my .c files and used a small tool to generate header files from them during the normal build.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of C#, the 3.0 [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx) states

> Because an assembly is a
>   self-describing unit of functionality
>   containing both code and metadata,
>   there is no need for #include
>   directives and header files in C#. The
>   public types and members contained in
>   a particular assembly are made
>   available in a C# program simply by
>   referencing that assembly when
>   compiling the program.

Answer (score 6):

Because they are leftovers from the past.

Modern language use the concept of modules and packages.

If you want to use a function/class that's defined in another file, import that file. The compiler figures out the symbols (i.e. names) so that you can use them.

The C/C++ approach: is extract the function/class definitions by hand and put them in another file, then do a text-inclusion of those definition anywhere you want to use them.

Answer (score 4):

In C, you cannot make forward references, ie. use a function not yet defined above its use. Headers are originally made for that, as references to implementation.

I looked at the accepted answer of the referenced question, and it is right. But today, compilation speed is a minor issue (except, perhaps, with very large apps: it takes 1/4hr to clean compile the app we have, at least on Windows). And details of implementation are hidden anyway, we usually look only at the API documentation, ie. the visible interface.

For the anecdote, I saw some C++ libraries implemented at 99% in headers (only having .cpp files where the system requested them), thus mimicking Java style (C# wasn't here at the time...).

Answer (score 3):

I would say that, ideally, all of the information should live in a single place and have a module system that will intelligently avoid recompiling/importing unnecessary details and then have the compiler be able to extract the interface-only information if necessary (eg, to ship with a library or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

They're not really needed in C# and Java, because you can specify the access level for each method (e.g. public or private), and besides you have reflectivity like you don't in C++.

Note that for non-OOP practices using header files is not really that bad.  You can for instance only declare which functions should be publicly available to clients in your header files, while keeping others hidden (and therefore non-accessible) by only declaring them in the .cpp or .c file.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that most OO languages get all of the mileage they need along these lines from having Interfaces.  It provides all the flexibility (i.e. - separating interface from implementation) of header files, while having stricter contracts with the clients using the interfaces (because they are enforced by the language/compiler).

Answer (score 1):

To me, headers in C and C++ are a big time and productivity sink.  Compile...  whoops, forgot to fix a method's signature.  Compile... whoops, need to add method a to class X.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of headers, the compiler's output needs to contain the description of code that compiler itself can understand. This was not easy with older linkers: the object files that they consumed could not be too smart. Hence the task of creating the description of the code was left to a human: the header file.

The newer languages either bypass the linker altogether (the interpreted and VM languages) or use custom linkers (Turbo Pascal, I assume Delphi too). Still, even now, when you deal with linker (or its younger sibling, dynamic library loader), you need to produce some sort of description of what's inside the library.

Answer (score 0):

Most other languages aren't nearly as obtuse and difficult to parse and compile as C++, so there the "performance optimization" of separating header and implementation is not so important.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ header files are basically a way to group variables that would otherwise need to be declared as externs in every compilation unit that they are used.

That however has not limited the complexity or diversity of problem domains that C/C++ can handle. Its just that the programming language evolved that way. Eventually all that matters is that the linker somehow figure out all the references and type of the variables that you have used in your program.

The way C/C++ does this is rather crude compared to the new crop of programming languages that seem to have native language support for handling outside references to variables and methods.