# function header and implementation in different files C

Tags: c, function, header, definition

How do you have a header file for a function and the implementation of that function in  different files? Also, how do you have main in yet another file and call this  function?
The advantage is so that this function will then be an independent component which can be reused, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++ why have header files and cpp files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/in-c-why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files)

Answer (score 8):

This is best illustrated by an example.

Say we want a function to find the cube of an integer.

You would have the *definition* (implementation) in, say, `cube.c`

```
int cube( int x ) {
  return x * x * x;
}
```

Then we'll put the function *declaration* in another file. By convention, this is done in a [header file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file), `cube.h` in this case.

```
int cube( int x );
```

We can now call the function from somewhere else, `driver.c` for instance, by using the `#include` directive (which is part of the C preprocessor)  .

```
#include "cube.h"

int main() {
  int c = cube( 10 );
  ...
}
```

Finally, you'll need to compile each of your source files into an object file, and then link those to obtain an executable.

Using *gcc*, for instance

```
$ gcc -c cube.c                 #this produces a file named 'cube.o'
$ gcc -c driver.c               #idem for 'driver.o'
$ gcc -o driver driver.c cube.c #produces your executable, 'driver'
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can implement any function in header files for better performance(when implementing libraries for example) as long are not referenced to a specific object(actually it won't compile that).
By the way even with that way, you have separate interface and implementation ;)
Of course you will have include gurads in you header files to avoid "multiple definition" errors.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, non-inline functions should be defined only once. If you put function defination 
in header files, you will get "multiple defination" link error when the header file is included more than once.

Comment: I won't put func defn in header file. I'll have foo.h and foo.c containing declaration and implementation repectively. How do I do that?