# C++ template functions

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

This Vec template supports several functions such as multiplying a vector by scalar and adding vector to another vector.

The thing that is confusing me is that why the overloading of the second `operator*` is outside of the class template?
The `operator*` which is declared in the class overloads vectorXscalar
The one declared outside supports scalarXvector

```
template <class T>
class Vec {
public:
    typename list<T>::const_iterator begin() const {
        return vals_.begin();
    }
    typename list<T>::const_iterator end() const {
        return vals_.end();
    }
    Vec() {};

    Vec(const T& el);
    void push_back(T el);
    unsigned int size() const;
    Vec operator+(const Vec& rhs) const;
    Vec operator*(const T& rhs) const; //here
    T& operator[](unsigned int ind);
    const T& operator[](unsigned int ind) const;
    Vec operator,(const Vec& rhs) const;
    Vec operator[](const Vec<unsigned int>& ind) const;

    template <class Compare>
    void sort(Compare comp) {
        vals_.sort(comp);
    }

protected:
    list<T> vals_; 
};

template <class T>
Vec<T> operator*(const T& lhs, const Vec<T>& rhs); //and here!

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ro, const Vec<T>& v);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function declaration inside or outside the class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075931/function-declaration-inside-or-outside-the-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `operator*` declared inside the template class could equally be written outside the class as

```
template <class T>
Vec<T> operator*(const Vec<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
```

It can be written inside the class with a single argument (representing the rhs) because there is the implied `*this` argument used as the lhs of the operator.

The difference with the `operator*` defined outside the class is that the lhs of the operator is a template type.  This allows the arguments to be supplied either way around when using the operator.

You are allowed to define the operator outside of a class with any arbitrary lhs and rhs types, but within the class are restricted to only varying the rhs.  The compiler would select the best match of any defined `operator*` given the argument types.

Comment: Your first sentence with the code you provided made things that my Lecturer couldn't explain to me well! 
You sir know how to explain things dont you? Thanks!! :)