# Why do we need to recompile source files that use a class fully defined in a header when the class's implementation is changed?

Tags: c++, compilation

Reading about encapsulation in Lippman book, I found the following pargraph

> Although user code need not change when a class definition changes,
>   the source files that use a class must be recompiled any time the class
>   changes.

Assuming I have the following code

```
class A {
private:
    int x;

public:
    A() { x = 0; }

    int x_plus();
}

int A::x_plus(){ return x + 1; }
```

if I changed the body of `x_plus()` to return `x+2` , why I shall recompile source file that use it ?

I think it's something related to linking process by C++ , am I right ?

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense.
You need to recompile the class definition (along with all the code that changed). All of that is both obvious and automatic.

Comment: @xyious, I am asking about the user code that will use my class. not class's source code.

Comment: C++ build tools use very simple dependency checking, they only look at the timestamp of the source file.  So if you would *not* use inline function definitions, keep the declaration in a .h file and the implementation in a .cpp file, then such a modification won't cause other source files to get rebuilt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put the function definition inside the class definition, it's treated as an inline function by default. This means that any caller could have the body of the function copied into it. If you change the definition, the callers will still contain the old definition unless you recompile them.

See [Function declaration inside or outside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075931/function-declaration-inside-or-outside-the-class)

If you change a function whose definition is not in the header file for the class, you don't need to recompile the callers, you just need to relink them. This is not considered a change to the class definition, so the quote from the Lippman book doesn't apply.

A simpler way to look at this is that the class definition should be in a `.h` file, while the code for the class will be in a `.cpp` file, which gets compiled into a `.o` file. If you make any changes to the `.h` file, you need to recompile anything that contains `<include filename.h>`. If you make any changes to the `.cpp` file, you'll recompile the `.o` file and relink the executables that use it. Application build tools (like `make` on Unix) should handle this automatically for you.

Comment: And if you're using LTO this can still happen even when not defined inline ;-)

Comment: I added the example myself, so I think it changed the meaning of the example.
assuming another situation with no inline functions, (Changing the implementation of functions defined outside the class)

Comment: If you change the implementation of non-inline functions outside the class definition, you don't need to recompile the callers, you just need to re-link them to the `.o` file for the class.

Comment: That's what I know, but I am bit confused by the statement in Lippman book

Comment: The book says "class definition". If the function definition isn't inside the class, it's not a change to the class definition.