# C++ undefined reference to method and What if all stuff go to .h?

Tags: c++, extern, undefined-reference

The simple C++ code I wrote below got compile error
**"undefined reference to 'featureExtract()'"**  (using codeblocks under windows),

in **`FeaureExtract.h`**

```
#ifndef FEATUREEXTRACT_H_INCLUDED
#define FEATUREEXTRACT_H_INCLUDED

extern void featureExtract();

#endif // FEATUREEXTRACT_H_INCLUDED
```

in **`FeatureExtract.cpp`**

```
#include "FeatureExtract.h"
void featureExtract()
{
    some code
}
```

in **`main.cpp`**

```
#include "FeatureExtract.h"
int main()
{
    featureExtract();
}
```

I have searched the SO using keyword "C++ undefined reference to" and read tens of entries (many are to class or under Linux), but I could not get my own problem addressed (I don't know why).
Thanks for any hint~

Before solving this problem, I have no choice but put all the staff in FeatureExtract.h, it works, but it seems not good. This post ( [Why have header files and .cpp files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/in-c-why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files) ) explains the main merit of .h files is "separating the interface from the implementation", I wonder if putting all interface and implementation in .h files will have other effects?

Thank you~

Comment: Are all files in the same codeblocks project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't linking both object files together into your final binary. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with codeblocks, but make sure all the `.cpp` files are added to your project.

Another less likely possibility is that somehow the name decoration is different between the two cpp files. Make sure you're using C++ to compile both files and that one doesn't compile as C code for example.

Comment: Thank you all, @Mark B @Zeta @Frobzig, I solved it. I remove the `.h` and `.cpp` from the project and then add them back to the project, no error anymore. I think it is because I once changed the `.h` file name and then changed the name back, something invisible happened.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine.  As Zeta said, are all files in the same project?