# The difference between ways of including files in C++

Tags: c++, header, include

Wherever I ask how to add a class or  a library to my C++ project , everyone says that I should make a .h file , use preprocessor directives , declare functions prototypes in it , and create a new .cpp file for writing down the functions in it and finally include the .h file in our main.cpp . 
But when I simply add a cpp/h  to my source files it works as well . So what is the point of creating a .cpp and .h if I can write all my code in one file and include it in my main.cpp ?

Comment: in simple words, better code management.

Comment: Did you try and find any previous answers to this beforehand? 
[read me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files-in-c)

Comment: As your code grows you will see why, young grasshopper.

Comment: @molbdnilo if you know the answer please write it , if you don't  please don't write senseless things

Answer (score 2):

- Splitting your code into files provides a useful logical grouping to help grok your program.
- Splitting will result in faster compilation in many cases.
- Splitting will allow you to do things with circular dependencies (although they should be avoided when possible).
- Some compilers will be unable to handle large projects that are all compiled into one `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

This potentially leads to two rather different types of problems.

The first is that it can lead to long build times. When you keep the .cpp files separate, you can compile that file when you change it, but otherwise just have the linker link to the functions in that file without re-compiling every time. As long as your projects are small, re-compiling all the code every time isn't a major problem, but if the project gets very big, it can quickly become a serious hassle.

The second issue is multiple definitions of the same function(s). Assume for example you've defined some functions in A.cpp, and you need to use those functions in both B.cpp and C.cpp. If you directly include the source code those functions (rather than just declarations) in B.cpp and C.cpp, then try to link B, and C together, you have multiple definitions of all the functions in A.cpp. The result in undefined behavior. In most cases, the linker will tell you the functions have been defined more than once, but you can't entirely depend on that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing little toy programs, it might be more effort than it is worth to break everything up in to logically seperated modules.  I keep several `/hacks` projects on my hard drives where I do testing and experiments, and they are typically just one big file.

But when you get in to working on real systems, things get much more complex.  Systems can be several *million* lines of code or more, in thousands of different subsystems.  Keeping all these systems seperated from each other provides many benefits in large, complex systems.

- Code is written for humans, not machines.  Breaking systems up in to many little files is like writing an essay with many paragraphs each consisting of several (but not too many) sentences.  Writing an entire 1000-word essay as a single sentance might be possible, but it will be very painful to read.  Similarly, it is much easier to find what your looking for in thousands of little files organized sanely than in one massive file.
- Breaking up files, especially header files, to be as small as possible but not smaller can help speed up compiles quite substantially.
- Breaking up modules can help to decouple disparate systems, and identify where artificial couplings exist.

All in all, the bottom line is it makes things *simpler*, and that's always a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

Having a clear, logical split between different "units" of your program helps keep it neat and tidy. This helps understanding what goes where, what uses what, and generally "how it all fits together". If you simply include everything into one large blob of code, it's very easy to "not properly separate things", so all of a sudden a variable in A.cpp is being used in B.cpp, rather than either declaring the variable as an "extern" in A.h, or better yet, have a function to access it from anywhere, but the actual variable is "protected" inside B.cpp, so nobody else gets to use it.

The technique of "keeping things separate" is called encapsulation - you only get to see the "bits" of the file that is actually being exposed by the header. That way, I, as a second programmer on your project, know which bits I can change (as long as it works the same) inside A.cpp - everything that isn't in A.h will be "fair game". What is in A.h, must be more carefully treated, because that means something outside A.cpp may be using it, and we need to look at where/how that is used before it can be changed.

This makes a big difference in large projects. When you have 100 or 200 lines of code, you can literally remember all the lines of code, and if you change something on line 150-160, you can easily remember that the same variable is also used on line 172 and 189, so you need to change there too. When your project is 2000 lines long, it's still manageable for one person to know most of everything at once. If you've written all of 100k lines, you can probably still manage it. When you have 1M lines of code, most of which someone ELSE wrote, you need good structure to be able to change things without ending up with a mess that doesn't work. Of course, you'll never get to work on a 5K line project if you don't show that you understand how it is supposed to be done in the first place.

Sorry, this got a bit long, but the general idea is: If you keep it clean, and neat, you have a better way of working, which will eventually lead to better software.

Comment: OK ... but my question a little differs . I ask why to include a .h , declare the function prototypes in it , and write the functions in a cpp if I can directly write them in a cpp without declarations ?

Comment: I thought that was what I was trying to explain: If you separate the .cpp files [by compiling one at a time], we KNOW that A.cpp uses something from B.cpp, because the compiler tells us when that happens. If you write everything in one large file, it's terribly hard to tell what's what, first of all, and second, it's possible (you don't have to, but you can) to use things in A.cpp from B.cpp without "telling" in the A.h or B.h that these belong together.

Comment: I don't mean why to separate the code . I ask why do I need to declare function prototypes in .h and write the functions in .cpp if I can write them in a .cpp and include it in main . for example I want to write a class in a separate file(not in main.cpp) . I can declare the class in a .h using #ifndef #define .. and write the class itself in a cpp and finally include the myclass.h in the main.cpp . But also I can make a myclass.cpp and write the class in it without the .h declarations and include it in main.cpp as well. So my question : Which is the difference between these two methods

Comment: Yes, and you could write it ALL in main.cpp - because that's essentially what including the .cpp file is. When you have 378000 lines of code, you may want to have it a little bit less complicated than that. Sure, when debugging, figuring out which source file to look at is simple. But finding out which line isn't going to be so fun. By splitting things, we can isolate components from each other, and by compiling one .cpp file at a time, we know that our isolation works. If you just include all your .cpp files into main.cpp, you can, even if it's not on purpose, use things that you shouldn't.