# MinGW .h compiled files not working: The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

My .exe file won't run if the file I compiled is .h type.

This is the C++ code I put:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int var = 0, sum = 0;
    while (std::cin >> var){
        sum += var;
    }
    std::cout << "sum " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use MinGW for compiling, and I named the file CTesting.h and compiled it and I get the following error running the exe:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows
>   you're running. Check your computer's system information to see
>   whether your need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the
>   program, and then contact the software publisher.

I do not get this error when I rename the source fill to a .cpp type.  It is my understanding that C++ used .h and .cpp files, is that incorrect? or am I doing something wrong/forgetting something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.h` extension here! MinGW will recognise `CTesting.h` as a ***header*** file. You have to use a ***source*** file extension (eg. `.cpp` for C++ or `.c` for C), so GCC can determine it correctly.

Please see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-file-name-suffix-71) for a list of all file extensions and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html#Header-Files) for GCC manual about header files.