# Compiling with g++ - including header files

Tags: c++, header, g++

I just have a  quick question as I'm trying to understand how to compile (in ubuntu 12.04) a main in c++ that includes a simple header file.

The command:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp add.cpp -Wall
```

Works fine. However, that confuses me about the point of the header file. At the moment, I have the simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {


  int a, b;
  cout << "Enter two numbers to add together" << endl;
  cin >> a >> b;
  cout << "Sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << add(a,b) << endl;

  return 0;

}
```

Where my "add.cpp" is simply adding the two numbers together.

Is the header file simply a replacement for the function prototype? Do I need to compile the header file separately or is it sufficient to include all of the .cpp files in the command line? I understand that if I need more files a makefile would be necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why have header files and .cpp files in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

The `#include` preprocessor code just replaces the `#include` line with the content of the corresponding file, which is `add.h` in your code. You can see the code after preprocessing with g++ argument `-E`.

You can put theoretically anything in the header file, and the content of that file will be copied with a `#include` statement, without the need to compiling the header file separately.

You can put all the `cpp` file in one command, or you can compile them separately and link them in the end:

```
g++ -c source1.cpp -o source1.o
g++ -c source2.cpp -o source2.o
g++ -c source3.cpp -o source3.o
g++ source1.o source2.o source3.o -o source
```

**EDIT**

you can also write function prototypes direct in cpp file like (with NO header file):

```
/* add.cpp */
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

```
/* main.cpp */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int x, int y);    // write function protype DIRECTLY!
// prototype tells a compiler that we have a function called add that takes two int as
// parameters, but implemented somewhere else.

int main() {
    int a, b;
    cout << "Enter two numbers to add together" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << "Sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << add(a,b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It also works. But using header files is preferred since prototypes might be used in multiple cpp files, without the need of changing every cpp file when the prototype is changed.

Comment: no need for `-o sourceX.o`, unless you want to change the name of the object file.

Comment: Ok but my confusion comes in the use of the header file... When running hte code, you still have to separately compile each .cpp file, right? Regardless of the header file? Or do you include the header file in the command line? Sorry, this is an area I haven't quite been able to get my head around!

Answer (score 1):

When using a header file (eg header.h), include only if it exists
 in the directory as described above:

~$ g++ source1.cpp source2.cpp source3.cpp -o main -Wall

Comment: I think you mean "if it DOES NOT exist in the directory as described"?