# Is the .m implementation file required if my header file contains only declared @properties

Tags: objective-c, header-files

I have some model classes that contain only @property declarations in the header file, therefore my .m implementation files are empty.

So my question is: are these .m files required if I have only @property declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is still required. The part that says:

```
@implementation MyClass
@end
```

is actually the most important part of a definition of a class. The header serves only as a forward declaration and doesn't have any functionality on its own.

To understand this well, some knowledge of the C language and its history is required, so I won't go into details. You can get some info from the answers here: [Why have header files and .cpp files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files-in-c)