# Multiple declarations of a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, makefile, multiple-definition-error

I am working on an assignment for a class and I am running into (what I think is) a basic issueIve tried looking at other answers but I cannot seem to find my issue.

When I run the commmand `make`, I get the following error:

```
    prog8lib.o: In function `Transform':
   .../prog8lib.cc:6: multiple definition of `Transform::Transform(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
    prog8.o:.../prog8lib.cc:6: first defined here
    prog8lib.o: In function `Transform':
   .../prog8lib.cc:6: multiple definition of `Transform::Transform(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
    prog8.o:.../prog8lib.cc:6: first defined here
```

This is the code that I am currently using. Can anyone spot my errors?

Thanks!!!

**prog8.cc:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "prog8lib.cc"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string start = argv[1];
    string end = argv[2];
    Transform(start, end);
}
```

**prog8lib.cc:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prog8lib.h"

Transform::Transform(string startWord, string endWord) {
    cout << "Test" << endl;
}
Transform::~Transform() {}
```

**prog8lib.h:**

```
#ifndef PROG8LIB_H
#define PROG8LIB_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Transform{
private:
    string start;
    string end;
public:
    Transform(string str, string str2);
    ~Transform();
};

#endif
```

**Makefile:**

```
OBJ = prog8.o prog8lib.o
OPTS = -g -c -Wall -Werror

trans: $(OBJ)
        g++ -o trans $(OBJ)

prog8.o: prog8.cc
    g++ $(OPTS) prog8.cc

prog8lib.o: prog8lib.cc prog8lib.h
        g++ $(OPTS) prog8lib.cc

clean:
        rm -f *.o *~
```

Comment: In prog8.cc, you included the proglib8.cc filed instead of the .h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
#include "prog8lib.cc"
```

in `prog8.cc` to

```
#include "prog8lib.h"
```

Otherwise the compiler will find two definitions of `Transform::Transform`: once in `prog8.cc` and once in `proglib8.cc`.

Answer (score 1):

you have declared a class in header file, and that is the file that you need to include in main.cpp..always include the header files, not the .cpp files..

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files-in-c](http://compilation%20order)