# Should I place a POD struct in a .h file or in a .cpp file?

Tags: c++

I need to write a few POD structs, but should I place them in a .h or in a .cpp file?

example

```
struct Vec2
{
    float x, y, z;
}
```

Should this be placed inside of Vec2.h or inside of Vec2.cpp?

Comment: Class definitions must go in a header if you intend to access them in another file, other than the corresponding cpp file.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what type of structure it is, it's about whether you want the same structure to be visible/usable from multiple .cpp files. If you're only going to use it in one .cpp, put it in that cpp, otherwise put it in a .h file.

Comment: [Why have header files and .cpp files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the information and the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to write a few POD structs, but should I place them in a .h or in a .cpp file?

There's nothing in a *real POD* as you're showing it, that needs to be implemented explicitly in a separate translation unit (`.cpp` file).

> Should this be placed inside of Vec2.h or inside of Vec2.cpp?

Just place

```
struct Vec2 {
    float x, y, z;
}; // <<<< note semicolon
```

in your header file, include it elsewhere and use it. There's no need for `Vec2.cpp`.