# How to include a C library for multiple files

Tags: c, include, libraries

I have a program that went like this:

```
//this is main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
#include "fileA.c"
#include "fileB.c"
...

//rest of main file
```

which worked fine but now when I replicated the exact same project (in VS) all the other files in the project don't seem to recognize the standard library #includes from some reason.

any help please?

Comment: C programs are compiled file by file, so in order for `#include`s to be recognized they need to be included in every file. Also, you should only include [header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files), not source files.

Comment: You should not normally `#include` C source files — you `#include` headers, but not (normally) source code.  There are exceptions — but they're rare and should remain exceptional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other files are independent files. As such, you must include the relevant header files in those files as well. Also, it is not considered a good practice to include .c files as it can easily result in linking errors due to multiple definitions.