# Object dependency in C++. What is the syntax for class composition?

Tags: c++, oop, syntax, composition

Class are have written my classes in different files. Such as:

```
-main.cpp
-ClassA.cpp
-ClassB.cpp
-ClassC.cpp
```

main.cpp has the #include for all classes, but I also need to access Object instantiated from ClassA in main inside ClassB and ClassC.

main.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.cpp"
#include "ClassB.cpp"
#include "ClassC.cpp"

ClassA objA;
ClassB objB(objA);
ClassB objC(objA);
```

.
.

classB.cpp

```
#include "ClassB.cpp" //How to avoid the double declaration and yet make the class recognizable?

class ClassB{
  public: 
   ClassA objA;
   ClassB(ClassA obj){
    this->objA = obj; // Is it the right way in C++?
   }
 };
```

I know it is not right. But why not? In Java makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: You generally should not include `.cpp` files. There's a good explanation of the basic C++ file structure and build process here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files#333964

Comment: C++ is not Java.  Things are done differently.

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm. Thank you for the information. But I already knew it before I post this question (Hence I am posting the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your classes in header files.  E.g. "ClassB.h":

```
#include "ClassA.h" // if it's referenced by the subsequent class declaration, you likely need that class's header file as well.

class ClassB{
  public: 
   ClassA objA;
   ClassB(ClassA obj);
 };
```

Implement your class in a .cpp file.  E.g. "ClassB.cpp"

```
#include "ClassB.h"
ClassB::ClassB(ClassA obj)
{
    objA = obj;
}
```

Repeat for your other classes.

Comment: So, the .h files are more like Java Interfaces.

Thank you very much. Let me see how it goes now.