# C++ Error: (class name) does not name a type

Tags: c++

I get the error 'MyIsland does not name a type', but do not get the error 'MyList does not name a type'. Why and how can I fix this?

Edit: I think it is due to having the list class in the header file but the MyIsland class in a separate file, but is there a way to fix this without moving the MyIsland class?

Here are a part of my files:

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

class ArchipelagoExpedition
{
 private:
  MyIsland* darr;
  int islands;

 public:
  ArchipelagoExpedition();
  ArchipelagoExpedition(int is);
...
```

Island.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

class MyIsland
{
private:
    MyList adjList;
    MyList visList;
public:
...
```

MyListAndNode.cpp

```
//list methods
...
}
```

header.h

```
//list and node class
...
```

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"I get the error 'MyIsland does not name a type', but do not get the error 'MyList does not name a type'"* Do you get it or not?

Comment: Do you want it to stop complaining about `MyIsland`, or *start* complaining about `MyList`? :-) @Ayxan, you *are* aware those types are *different,* yes?

Comment: @paxdiablo I totally missed that! Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @paxdiablo, from my limited understanding, since MyIsland gets an error, MyList should also get an error. I added an edit near the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program cannot find `MyIsland`. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/333964/11802207) to find out why.

The declarations of your classes should be in header files (`.h`, `.hpp`...), and the implementations in source files (`.cc`, `.cpp`...). In your case, I would do something like this:

- class `List`

  - `list.hpp` (declaration)
  - `list.cpp` (implementation)
- class `Island`

  - `island.hpp` (declaration)
  - `island.cpp` (implementation)

In the above case, you should include `list.hpp` in `island.hpp`, `island.hpp` in `main.cpp` and it will work.

---

Answer (score 0):

Oh... I had the same problem now. It was caused by the declaration of an enum with the same element as the name of the class, like:

```
enum Templates
{
    Temp1,
    Temp2
};
class Temp1
{
};
class Temp
{
    Temp1 m_temp1; // error here
};
```

That's why enums should be written by capital letters. Check if you do not have something similar.

Comment: "That's why enums should be written by capital letters" is a bit too general advice

Comment: Yes, you are right. In that case, it would spare me some time though