# Include declaration but not definition in main file C++

Tags: c++, c++11, file-handling

When using multiple files in **C++**, for example: **main.cpp**, **definition.cpp**, **declaration.h**

```
// declaration.h
int Myfunc();
```

```
//definition.cpp
#include "declaration.h"

int MyFunc() {return 5;};
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "declaration.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << Myfunc() << std::endl;
}
```

**Why do I *not* need to include the definition file into the main file?** How can the program know the definition of `Myfunc()` when I only have included the declaration?

Comment: How are you compiling the program? Is there a configuration file of any sort, or is this a Visual Studio project?

Comment: The definition is included into the executable in the linking step of the build process. See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6264249/9988487 for more details.

Comment: It's the responsibility of Linker.

Comment: I think the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/333964/5105949) explains your problem.

Comment: Because of the next phase: "Linking". Usually what happens: Compilation does `definition.cpp => definition.o` and `main.cpp => main.o` Then we link the object files into an executable:   `main.o + definition.o => application`

Comment: Including the header makes the names used in source file searched in that header and other headers. The compilers is satisfied with a name declaration like in your case when it compilation terminates there are object files for each translation unit. The linker links those object file (containing definitions) with some other libraries generating the executable file. If the linker doesn't find the definition it fails to link.

Comment: I wrote some articles about this problem; you may find them [here](https://yact.tech/en/posts/05_declarations_and_definitions_I.html) and [here](https://yact.tech/en/posts/06_declarations_and_definitions_II.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Declaration is like a signature of the function and at compile time only the signature is required (What variable to pass and what the function will return so that you can write your other code around it). Actual call to function is resolved during the link time. If you will include the definition in the header file and if that header file is included in multiple source file then there will be multiple definitions of the same function.

Comment: Thanks! This together with @MartinYork 's comment answered my question!